# Can I make this bash script that writes to multiple files run any faster?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have a script that reads in lines from a file, takes the first column of each line, and appends to a file named that line (I am trying to write many different files, named $id.txt).

Is it possible to have a script that does anything faster than this (on a single-node machine)? Note that I use `read -r` and `id="$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}')"` because I have tab-separated fields and there are certain characters like backslashes in some fields that I want to keep.

```
    while read -r line
    do
        id="$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}')"
        echo "$line" >> $id.txt
    done < $1
```

Some characteristics of my input:

- the output `$id.txt` files are not that large, usually a few hundred lines on average and up to a few thousand lines
- the id's are actually already sorted and the lines come in continuous blocks, i.e.:

> ```
> abc ...
> abc ...
> def ...
> def ...
> def ...
> def ...
> ghi ...
> ghi ...
> ```

Comment: You're writing each line one at a time; why not buffer them up and write a bigger block?

Answer (score 6):

Too much work.

```
awk '{ print >> $1".txt" }' "$1"
```

Comment: `awk '{ print >> $1 }' "$1" mybigfile.txt` generates the error: "...makes too many open files" after about 20 files for me. How to I get around this? My number of files is in the thousands.

Comment: I can do `awk '{ print >> $1".txt"; close($1) }' "$1"` successfully; is this the right way to do it? It definitely slows things down.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that your slowness is coming from doing `$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}'` for every line, which means the operating system needs to go through the work of creating two new processes for every line, made worse by `awk` being an interpreter.  You should condense this into one script using something like awk (by itself) or Perl.